# Input type="time" on Safari

Tags: html, safari

I've been using:

```
<input type="time">
```

for most of my pages and testing it on Chrome.
To my dismay, it turns out that on Safari, this input type refers back to a text field. Any idea why it does this?

Comment: Because not all browsers support that.

Comment: So, is there a time format that works on all browsers?

Comment: http://diveintohtml5.info/forms.html#type-date

Comment: Also, see: http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime

Answer (score 3):

**

> The input type "time" was not working on safari because - type="time"
>   is not supported in Safari version(may the version you are using) or Internet Explorer 12 and earlier
>   versions**

Answer (score -1):

This appears to be supported from iOS 5.0.

See here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/InputTypes.html

Comment: Safari on macOS is different from Safari on iOS.